# Embedding Mappoint 2010 Control in C# WinForm Creates Registry Error In Win7 (64-bit)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7, mappoint

I have a WinForms application with an embedded MapPoint control that I've been maintaining for about 5 years now.

The application originally used MapPoint 2004, then 2006, and now we're upgrading to 2010.

Within my development environment (VS2008/.NET 2.0 for the project) the application runs fine.

Once I create an installer and install the app and try to run that, I start encountering problems.  First the application prompts the UAC in Windows 2007 64 bit, though I don't have any code that modifies the filesystem or other protected systems.

If I choose "Yes" to allow the program to run, as soon as I try to create a new instance of a map to use within my map control

```
this._activeMap = this._mapCtrl.NewMap(MapPoint.GeoMapRegion.geoMapNorthAmerica);
```

I get a messagebox from MapPoint with the following error:

> Your registry settings were not copied correctly. To correct these settings, run setup again for this application.

I'm aware of the KB article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314590) regarding this error in Streets & Tips, but MapPoint 2010 runs fine on its own, and as I said, the app runs fine from within VS or when run from a non-protected folder (e.g. if I do an x-copy of the files to my user's directory, it runs fine).

Answer (score 1):

We received the same MapPoint error (along with others) on our install.  We use NSIS for our install packages; once we ran it with elevated permissions the errors disappeared.  I wish I could give you more details but I was not me who coded our installer.  I was simply told how we got passed the MapPoint issue. I hope it at least points you in the right direction and helps you narrow your research.

Answer (score 0):

Yes elevated install permissions are typically required anyway. My experience is more for MapPoint add-ins rather than apps that use the ActiveX control. There, I use the Visual Studio installed and Add-in Express, which has special settings for UAC handling. I don't think they have anything for using Office/MapPoint ActiveX controls, but it might be worth looking.